# dogecoin wallet client dependencies (boost)

Tags: compiling, qt, make, bitcoin, boost

I seem to be missing something boost related.

Dogecoin gives the requirements as:

`qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libssl-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev`

https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/doc/readme-qt.rst

compile error:

```
s/db/build_unix -Ic:/deps/ssl/include -Ibuild -Ibuild -o build/net.o src/net.cpp
src/main.cpp:17:53: fatal error: boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ 
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ apt-cache search libboost1.53-all-dev
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ 
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$
```

see also:

http://b.agilob.net/such-address-many-dig-on-linux-wow/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-all-dev
```

Then

```
make -j2 -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=-
```

if you're making the daemon version. The USE_UPNP=- nullifies the need to install miniupnpc. As far as libqrencode, that is option as well.

Comment: ok, that seems to have done the trick :)   it's taking a very long time to synch, but there's a GUI, so, as far as I can tell, the compile completed.